# Vb.net how to get the number after decimal places

Tags: vb.net

in Vb.net how to get the number after decimal places.

I tried below code.

```
Dim number As Decimal = 143.500
Dim wholePart As Integer = Decimal.Truncate(number)
Dim fractionPart As Decimal = number - wholePart
Dim secondPart3 As Integer

secondPart3 = Replace(fractionPart, "0.", "0")
```

then the result is coming 500, but when i tried 143.050 its giving 50 it should show 050

Thanks

Comment: What you've actually described here makes very little sense. `143.500` is the same number as `143.5`, so why should the result be `500` rather than `5`? Are you saying, with out actually saying, that you actually want the number of thousandths? If so then you should simply multiply the fractional part by 1000. If not then you ought to actually describe what you actually want. Numbers do not inherently have leading or trailing zeroes. That's just a way to represent them. Treat them as numbers, not text.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting 500? It must be 5, and for `143.050` the output should be `05` Because 0 after the last Integer number after decimal point is valueless. If you use `String` instead of `Decimal`, then you will get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. i got it with sample below code

```
Dim numar As Double
If Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, numar) Then

    Dim rmndr As Double
    rmndr = numar Mod 1
    If rmndr = 0 Then
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = Split(CStr(TextBox1.Text), ".")(1)
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73441166/1920035)) is unnecessarily complex. You were on the right track in your original post, but conflated numeric values with formatted string values. Because while 050 are 50 are the same numeric value, when you implicitly call ToString on the value (or explicitly with the wrong formatting) then you would always get 50 because the prefixing 0 is unnecessary when working with numeric values.

What you should do is:

1. Get the integral digits of the decimal value
2. Convert the underlying decimal value to a String
3. (optionally) Format the String specifying the level of precision
4. Drop the integral digits off converted string

Here is an example:

```vb
Private Function GetFractionalDigits(value As Decimal) As String
    Dim integralDigits = Decimal.Truncate(value)
    Return value.ToString().Remove(0, integralDigits.ToString().Length + 1)
End Function

Private Function GetFractionalDigits(value As Decimal, precisionSpecifier As Integer) As String
    If (precisionSpecifier < 0) Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("precisionSpecifier", "precisionSpecifier cannot be less than 0")
    End If
    Dim integralDigits = Decimal.Truncate(value)
    Return value.ToString("N" & precisionSpecifier).Remove(0, integralDigits.ToString().Length + 1)
End Function
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SBOXG0

Comment: Many thanks, sorry I didn't explain with my answer, because number amount convert into Word, first part converted into Word, but after decimal need to put the digit exactly showing in amount that's why